# I need help identifying microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, identification, timer, atmel, light

it is from a light and service reminder timer board. it looks like ATtiny26 but osc connection is on wrong pins(3-4 not 7-8) pin 6 is gnd, 16 is marked Hz, 10 is light relay signal (17 hours on 7 off), 19 is to service led(6-month interval) . there is a bi-weekly service indicator led aswell. is it possible this is a ATtiny26 and the external osc is for timer?[image: ic in question, also note the osc circuit connected, out of osc(TT4.00M) connected to pin 3]

Comment: Could it be that the uC runs on the internal oscillator, and the pins 3 and 4 serve to detect the ticks (pin changes) from a slow 32KHz oscillator? What is the value of OSC1 on your board?

Comment: It's probably made by some little-known Asian company.

Comment: This is an SOP-20 and you can find it on Kynix Semiconductor website.  From my research, I have not been able to find a datasheet for this part.  I believe its a part made in Hong Kong

Comment: This is obviously not a serious company. When you click datasheet on their web page, it takes you to alldatasheet.com. Probably this is some illegal copy-cat part.

Comment: possibly a clone or similar to  http://www.keil.com/dd/docs/datashts/hynix/gms97xx051_ds.pdf

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as because a proprietary microprocessor is going to be nearly impossible to find.